# How to pass a value to MarkupString content in Blazor components?

Tags: c#, html, web, razor, blazor

I am calling WebApi to GET Html code of page.
I also use a SharedComponent where I pass this code as ChildContent:

```cs
<div>
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

}
```

Afer I call the API, in my parent component I pass the code as ChildContent:

```cs
<SharedEmailTemplate>
  @TemplateCode
 </SharedEmailTemplate>
```

Untill this everything works fine. I can display the component, all of the HTML markups works.

But in my HTML I'm using a placeholder that I want to changed based on my input:

The message is: {{ message }}

Is there any way to do that in Blazor without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I mean-- html is just text.  So use one of C#'s many string methods for replacing the text.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0